# Remove slashes from sqlite

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, flexbuilder

I am creating an application in Flex that uses an embedded SQLite database. The data in the database contains quotes and other special characters which are escaped using a backslash or '\'.

Before I retrieve the data and render it in a Flex text area control I want to remove the '\'. Is there any function in Flex which can help me do this - some equivalent of stripslashes() in PHP?

Thanks & Regards,
Vinayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native method. Here is a result for ["as3 stripslashes"](http://snipplr.com/view/21968/actionscript-3-version-of-the-php-stripslashes-function/) from Google.

Comment: Thanks! I think this should suffice.